# How to convert a date to a number

Tags: excel, vba, type-mismatch

The following macro works when using one variable (`i`) as integer to create a serial number.

```vb
Sub Test1()
 
Dim i As Integer
i = Application.InputBox("How many days did the resource work in this period?")

For i = 10001 To 10000 + i
    ActiveCell.Value = i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

However, I want the initial value of the counter to correspond to the DATEVALUE of any date I input (instead of 10001 or any static number above) and then increment my output serial number from that initial value up:

```vb
Sub Test2()
'
' This is to create part of the unique ID using DATEVALUE
'

Dim StartDate As String
StartDate = Application.InputBox("Enter first date in this period", "[d]dMMMyyyy, e.g. 1Dec2021")

Dim i As Integer
i = Application.InputBox("How many days did the resource work in this period?")

For i = Int(DateValue("StartDate")) To Int(DateValue("StartDate")) + i
    ActiveCell.Value = i
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

I get

> type mismatch run-time error 13.

I tried to convert the string variable I assign as `StartDate` into an integer.

I think once the mismatch is resolved, I have to use `Long` instead of `Integer` as the MS Excel date serial numbers are large enough to lead to an overflow error.

Comment: None of the code you've posted makes any sense to me. For one thing, you use `i` to get user input, and then immediately throw it away with `For i = 10001 To 10000 + i`. Secondly, you can't modify the value of a loop counter within the loop - what's the point of the loop if you're fooling with the value that's being looped on? Third, you cast `i` to an `Int` after getting a `DateValue`, which means you wanted a date after telling VB that `i` is an `Integer`. Fourth, the for loop I quoted makes no sense. It loops from a high # to a low # without a negative. What are you trying to doh?

Comment: As I said, the first block of quote works fine (the ```For i = 10001 To 10000 + I``` part).  Try it yourself. What I'm trying to do is get a serial number that doesn't start from a fixed number (macro Test()), but from the date-equivalent number that I input into the InputBox. And I want to make it easier for the user not to have to input that number (e.g. 39448) themselves, but just enter a date and have the DATEVALUE function do it for them.

Comment: `Integer` is a 16-bit signed integer type, so max value is 32,767. Excel stores dates as numeric values - *all* numeric values in fact, as `Double`. If you do `Debug.Print CDbl(Now)`, you'll get a number in the 44K range, which is well beyond what an `Integer` can hold and yes that's an overflow error. But the type mismatch occurs immediately before that, when `DateValue` receives the string literal value `"StartDate"` instead of the content of the `StartDate` local variable. Lose the string-delimiter quotes!

Comment: ...and validate user inputs... it comes from a user, so it could be anything.. if you want bug-free, you can never trust user input to be in any way, shape, or form, anywhere near what your program actually needs to function properly ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for me it's very useful the Cint, Cdbl, clng, cstr, cdate statements. This is to convert a variable to another type of variable.
Date is a variable that can hold a Long Type variable. A date can't be converted to an integer.
So, e.g., I usually do CLng(now()) to convert the today date to a number (long)

```
Sub Test3()

Dim StartDate As String, inputDays As String, i As Long, xRow As Long

question: 
StartDate = InputBox("Enter first date in this period", "[d]dMMMyyyy, e.g. 1Dec2021")
If StartDate = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'if the user Cancel or don't type, end the routine
If Not IsDate(StartDate) Then GoTo question 'if not is date, go back to the "question" line code


questionDays:
inputDays = InputBox("How many days did the resource work in this period?")
If inputDays = vbNullString Then Exit Sub 'the same, if is empty, quit
If Not IsNumeric(inputDays) Then GoTo questionDays 'the same, if not is a number, back to the second question

    xRow = 0
    For i = CLng(CDate(StartDate)) To CLng(CDate(StartDate)) + inputDays
        With ActiveCell.offset(xRow, 0) 'from the active cell, offset x rows
            .value = Format(CDate(i), "dd-mm-yyyy")
        End With
        xRow = xRow + 1 'add 
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code helped resolved the type mismatch. However, I wanted to get the serial number equivalent of the dates so I just added ```.NumberFormat = "General"``` under your essentially ```.Value = i ```, which completed the job for me.